# Error in installing packages in R

Tags: r

I tried installing `rtweet()` in R but it shows the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rtweet’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- imp[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: Could you try installing `Rcpp` and post the error that returns, please

Comment: I tried that too. It shows: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rtweet’ in loadNamespace(j <- imp[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: upload screenshot of your r console

Comment: Please do not encourage posting screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

As Russ said, you should try to install `Rcpp` before:

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
```

Or you could use the line:

```
install.packages("rtweet", dependencies = TRUE)
```

It will install `rtweet` and all dependencies like `Rcpp`

You could also, try to install it directly from URL:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/index.html")
```

And if still fails, go directly to issues from rtweet (https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/issues) ;-)

And also be careful, because R packages are case-sensitive!

Have a nice day!